# How to constantly check for changes in system time?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that makes a sound every hour, how would I do this?

I thought maybe constantly checking the system time and if it's equal to either "1:00 2:00 3:00 etc..." then play a sound, but I don't know how to do this, some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You've already answered your own question! Try Googling **check system time in <language or platform you are using>** and do something like that. Of course there may be better overall designs, like Unix crontab, but Google really is your friend for these small programming tasks.

Comment: Ya, google check system time and then put that code inside a timer's tick event handler if you want to keep checking it periodically

Comment: You could use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) and set its interval to the time remaining. Then when the Tick event is raised, calculate the time to the next hour and set its interval accordingly - this will avoid drift. Other timers available if you're not doing this in a Windows Form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Timer, set Interval for 1000 (1 second) and in Tick event check current time

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        'check time here and put it in Label1
        Label1.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss")

        'if currenttime = alarmtime then do something
        If TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss") = "10:01:00" Then Beep()
    End Sub
```

For more info how to read current time:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer, set the interval for 500 milliseconds (.5s), setting to 1 second could cause the tick to be missed. This will fire the tick event, check if the current time minutes and seconds are equal to zero, then fires. The timer is disabled between the sound firing in case the timer checks again within the second (because the timer is called ever half a second).

```
ReadOnly _tmr As New Timer
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    _tmr.Interval = 500
    AddHandler _tmr.Tick, AddressOf tmr_Tick
    _tmr.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim curDateTime As DateTime = Now

    If curDateTime.Minute = 0 And curDateTime.Second = 0 Then
        _tmr.Enabled = False
        PlaySound()
        _tmr.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub PlaySound()
    '// Play Sound
End Sub
```